# Broadcast no refresca correctamente el navegador desde la consola de Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, broadcast

Tengo una aplicación en rails con este Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "3.1.3"

gem "rails", "~> 7.1.3", ">= 7.1.3.2"
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
gem "puma", ">= 5.0"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "turbo-rails"
gem "stimulus-rails"
gem "cssbundling-rails"
gem "jbuilder"
gem "redis", ">= 4.0.1"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ windows jruby ]
gem "bootsnap", require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri windows ]
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console"
  gem "error_highlight", ">= 0.4.0", platforms: [:ruby]
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end

gem "hotwire-rails", "~> 0.1.3"
```

En el index.html.erb tengo este código:

```
<p id="notice" style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Tweets</h1>

<%= render "tweets/form", tweet: @tweet %>

<%= turbo_stream_from "tweets" %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "tweets" do %>
  <%= render @tweets %>
<% end %>
```

En el modelo tengo este código:

```
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord

  validates :body, presence: true

  after_create_commit { broadcast_prepend_to "tweets" }
  after_update_commit { broadcast_replace_to "tweets" }
  after_destroy_commit { broadcast_remove_to "tweets" }
end
```

Cuando creo el registro por consola, lo actualiza de inmediato en el navegador, pero cuando lo actualizo o lo borro por consola, no lo actualiza de inmediato en el navegador.

¿Alguna idea que pudiera ser?